# How can I change screen resolution from command prompt in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, resolution, cmd.exe

I need to change my screen's resolution from the command prompt, I've tried QRes and NirCmd and both weren't able to change the screen resolution (i've already checked the syntax). Is there any way to it?

Comment: what do you mean "They didn't work"?? Add details please

Comment: [ScriptingGuy on Resolution](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/07/21/how-can-i-determine-the-current-screen-resolution-being-used-on-a-computer/): "For better or worse (and yes, we agree that this qualifies as “for worse”) there’s no built-in way to change the screen resolution using a script. Sorry."  Although that is from 2005, pre-dating Windows 10, so maybe the situation's changed.  [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservercore/thread/70af1896-58f3-4f69-ae24-e37de2adb10b/) has some possible solutions (if reboot acceptable)?

Answer (score 6):

You can try the free tool I developed: http://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/

Just call it like this:

`ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=800 /h=600`

Comment: Working solution right here.

Answer (score 2):

#### I've NirCmd and it wasn't able to change the screen resolution

> Actually [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/) from [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) **can** change the screen
>   resolution:
>
> ```
> setdisplay {monitor:index/name} [width] [height] [color bits] {refresh rate} {-updatereg} {-allusers}
> ```
>
> Changes your display settings.
>
> - The `[width]` and `[height]` parameters
>     represents the number of pixels on your screen.
> - The `[color bits]`
>     parameter represents the number of colors shown on your screen (8 -
>     256 color, 16 - 16bit color, 24 - 24bit color, and so on).
> - `{refresh rate}` is an optional parameter that specifies the monitor refresh
>     rate.
> - If you specify the `{-updatereg}` parameter, the new settings
>     will be saved in the Registry.
> - If you specify both `{-updatereg}` and
>     `{-allusers}` parameters, the new settings will be saved in the
>     Registry for all users.
> - If you have multiple monitors, you can use the optional monitor
>     parameter, which specifies for which monitor you want to change the
>     display settings.
>
>   You can specify the monitor by index (0 for the
>     first monitor, 1 for the second one, and so on) or by specifying a
>     string in the system monitor name.
>
>   The monitor name can be found in
>     the Device manager of Windows: Right click on the monitor item, and
>     then choose 'Properties'. The string displayed in the 'location' field
>     is the monitor name.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> setdisplay 800 600 24 -updatereg
> setdisplay 1024 768 24 90
> setdisplay 1024 768 8
> setdisplay monitor:1 1024 768 24 90
> setdisplay monitor:name1 1024 768 24 90
> ```

Source [NirCmd Command Reference - setdisplay](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setdisplay.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.